# Directional derivatives in two directions

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

How can I take a directional derivative in two directions?

I mean,$$D_{xy}f(0,0)$$

Because when I have something like  $$D_{x}f(0,0),$$ I just use that my direction is in the x axis, $ \vec u=(1,0)$

I guessed that maybe is the $x$-$y$ direction so I could use $\vec u=(1,1)$ but I'm supposed to prove that $$D_{xy}f(0,0) \neq D_{yx}f(0,0)  .$$

So I suppose that I misunderstood this direction.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Usually, $D_{xy}f(0,0)$ is understood as $D_x D_y f(0,0)$.

Comment: According to Claurot's (or Schwartz's) theorem, listed here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives , you'll get that the cross partials are equal IF the the second partial derivatives are continuous.   So whatever function f they gave you better not have continuous second partials in order for you to prove that inequality